# AES Decryption Sample code

Tags: iphone, aes, encryption-symmetric

From past one week i m trying to decrypt a data that is encrypted in java server my values are as follows

> Decrypted value-->admin
>  cipher
>   key-->2020a7db17ca8071de72ef439405b570
>  Enciphered
>   data--f118404f2b7d98a744d2fa24c0d21167

and my code is

```
 NSString* cipherText = @"f118404f2b7d98a744d2fa24c0d21167";
    NSLog(@"CipherText = %@",cipherText);
    NSString* expectedText = @"admin";
    NSLog(@"expexted text = %@",expectedText);
    Cipher* cipher = [[Cipher alloc] initWithKey:@"2020a7db17ca8071de72ef439405b570"];
    NSLog(@"cipher = %@",cipher);
    NSData* cipherTextData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:cipherText];
     NSLog(@"ciphertextdata= %@",cipherTextData);
    NSData* plainTextData = [cipher decrypt:cipherTextData];
     NSLog(@"plaintextdata= %@",plainTextData);
    NSString* plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainTextData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"plaintext= %@",plainText);
```

but i m not able to get the value `cipherTextData` and `plainTextData`. It is always showing null. Anyone please help

Comment: why did you use "dataWithBase64EncodedString" ?

Comment: @meccan i am following the [Java and iPhone AES interoperability](http://watchitlater.com/blog/2010/02/java-and-iphone-aes-interoperability/). so i am using that .. if not that which one can i use please help

Comment: i think your cipherTest isn't base64 encoded

Comment: can you please test your code with these Attributes: http://watchitlater.com/blog/2010/02/java-and-iphone-aes-interoperability/#comment-9998

Comment: which attribute ??? i didnt get any

Comment: NSString* cipherText = @”lVKmlQnR02uCC7B36VRypFDMlJTWDP/jdm01Y1iRV576eA/XSK5xvMlIDd81FnnmjrE90BB/MlU7uSH/7JL+xA==”;
NSString* expectedText = @”Why are all crypto APIs so bloody hideous to use?”;
Cipher* cipher = [[Cipher alloc] initWithKey:@”password0″];

Comment: no it is also not working here ciphertextdata is itself showing null value...what might be the problem

Comment: Works for me: https://github.com/carlj/AES-Test

Comment: @meccan ciphertextdata = **<7f5d7ce3 4e1fd9be ddf7c6bb e387767d adb87347 76d75ebb 7f5d7ce3 4e1fd9be ddf7c6bb e387767d adb87347 76d75ebb>** but i guess problem with decrypt method please help

Comment: have you download and run my github example Project ?

Comment: ya the given ciphertext will work, but using that if i try to encrypt my values .plaintext is now also showing null value

Comment: as i mention at the beginning, i think your cipherText text isn't correct for the decryption. Your cipherText for the plainText "admin" and the password "2020a7db17ca8071de72ef439405b570" should be QsAGjAVPpoAiJeMjJgBSAw== and not f118404f2b7d98a744d2fa24c0d21167 . So please check your java implementation